# Using System.Web.Optimization Bundling, How Can I access The Result of a Built Bundle?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net

I need to write some bundled CSS to the page, but can figure out how to get the actual content of a StyleBundle to do that.  Is there an (easy) way?

Answer (score -1):

Presuming you have a bundle set up like so: 
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

In your CSHTML file, do the following:
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

Comment: That doesn't write the contents of the bundle to the page, it writes a link to the bundle to the page